# Remove a broken repository from Kali Linux

Tags: apt, kali-linux

```
sudo apt-get update                              
[sudo] password for kali: 
Hit:1 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bullseye InRelease
Ign:3 https://repo.avcdn.net/linux-av/deb kali-kali-rolling InRelease 
Err:4 https://repo.avcdn.net/linux-av/deb kali-kali-rolling Release    
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.125.3.216 443]
Hit:2 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease                 
Reading package lists... Done                    
E: The repository 'https://repo.avcdn.net/linux-av/deb kali-kali-rolling Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried and failed to install avast from its repositories. Now running `sudo apt update` is returning errors. How can I fix it?

Comment: "_I want do `sudo apt update`_" - what's stopping you?

Comment: what's your question? ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: if you have to ask, then Kali Linux is probably not for you ... it is for use by experts ... get yourself a user friendly Linux distribution such as Ubuntu or Mint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the avast repository from your apt sources. It is either in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` or a separate file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see if you visit the URL https://repo.avcdn.net/linux-av/deb/dists/ using a regular web browser, this repository has no packages available for a distribution named `kali-kali-rolling`.

> ### Index of /deb/dists/
>
> ```
>  Name                                        Last modified      Size
>  ..
>  debian-bookworm/                            12-Jul-2023  9:54  -
>  debian-bullseye/                            12-Jul-2023  9:54  -
>  debian-buster/                              12-Jul-2023  9:54  -
>  ubuntu-bionic/                              12-Jul-2023  9:54  -
>  ubuntu-focal/                               12-Jul-2023  9:54  -
>  ubuntu-jammy/                               12-Jul-2023  9:54  -
> ```

Of course an anti-malware package is likely to have its own update mechanism for malware signatures, but the fact that currently **nothing** in this repository seems to have been updated at all since 12-Jul-2023 does not exactly fill me with confidence about this package repository.

Avast's main anti-malware product has apparently had a new major release in mid-December: https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=325690.0

The facts that there is no mention at all about Linux in that release notification and the discussion after it, and [Avast's product support page](https://support.avast.com/en-us/index/) does not mention Linux support at all, make me think the Linux version of this anti-malware product may have been quietly abandoned.

An anti-malware product that is not up to date will only give you **a false sense of security**.